# Is there a way in mongodb to add a filter/criteria to an existing filter only if the field is not null in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to include a filter of a date in my MongoDB query only if that date is not null.

For eg. if I have 2 date

`{ date1 : ISODate( <somedate> ) , date2 : null }`

my query should only include the criteria from date1 and not date2 and if

```
{ date1 : ISODate( <somedate> ) , date2 : ISODate( <somedate> ) }
```

then in this case the comparison should be first on date1 and then on date2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the $cond like this { $cond: { if: , then: , else:  } } in your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: thanks... i wrote a mongodb aggregation that uses $project to query out the desired output with $cond, and then  used $match to for comparing... however it only returns the fields that are present  in $project part of the aggregate along with _id...  is there any way so that i can have the exact document returned from the query.... currently I am using $unset to hide the temporary field I used in $project and also individually setting other fields as <field> : 1 in $project to make them available in the output